# I am getting Error on Sucuri Mallware scan on Joomla for SectionCategoryArticleList component

Tags: component, fatal-error

> Site error detected. Details: http://sucuri.net/malware/php-error-fatal-error?v6
>   **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in **/home/project/public_html/components/com_sectioncategoryarticlelist/views/sectioncategoryarticlelist/view.html.php** on line **28**

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

```
<?php
/**
 * @Project    SectionCategoryArticleList
 * @author     Mathias Hortig
 * @package    SectionCategoryArticleList
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2011-2012 tuts4you.de . All rights reserved.
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL version 2
*/

// no direct access

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');


class SectionCategoryArticleListViewSectionCategoryArticleList extends JViewLegacy
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root(true).'/components/com_sectioncategoryarticlelist/css/sectioncategoryarticlelist.css');
    $document->addScript(JURI::root(true).'/components/com_sectioncategoryarticlelist/js/sectioncategoryarticlelisttoggle.js');
        $model = &$this->getModel();
        $menu = JSite::getMenu()->getActive();
        $params = $menu->params;

        $this->assignRef( 'HTML', $model->GetCategories($params->get('linkcategories',1), $params->get('usetoggle',0), $params->get('defaulttoggle',0)));
        $this->assignRef( 'pretext', $params->get('pretext'));
        $this->assignRef( 'posttext', $params->get('posttext'));
        $this->assignRef( 'headline', $params->get('headline'));

        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is old legacy code, so am I right in assuming this is on a Joomla 1.5 site?

Comment: No, it could be a 2.x site, or even an early 3.x site, if the developer wasn't keeping current with PHP. Later versions of PHP would throw up at calling a non-static method statically, but PHP hasn't always been that picky.

Comment: @Rakhi, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the variable $params isn't getting set.

Could be several reasons this is happening, among them that there isn't a menu item set in the current URL.

As @lodder noted, this is old code. The mechanism involving the static call of getMenu from the site application was deprecated years ago; nobody should be using it anymore. (Don't remember precisely when it happened, but I think it was nearly a decade ago. I think it may have even been deprecated before this code was **written**, given the copyright date.)

Overall, my advice would be first to get this thing updated to something more nearly current, and if that's not possible to look at what the

```
JSite::getMenu()->getActive()
```

is returning. I suspect that's at the heart of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are no details provided behind your link (404 error).
I just see an old component php-error, maybe because of the Joomla 1.5 code inside. Have a look at the [Joomla Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page).

Probablly the developer should review his component again.